json4s: parsing of datetime issue
When I execute
    DateParser.parse("2024-11-15T11:37:48.256593Z", DefaultFormats.lossless)

I receive following result
result = {DateParser$ZonedInstant@3693} ZonedInstant(1731670924593,sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null])
 instant = 1731670924593
 timezone = {ZoneInfo@3660} "sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]"

But when I'm trying to check yhe millis back, i.e. on https://www.epochconverter.com, I receive
GMT: Friday, 15 November 2024 г., 11:42:04.593

that is approximately 5 mins greater than the source value

This looks like a bug. I suggest you open an issue on their GitHub.
For the record, it seems to come from the extra 3 digits after the milliseconds. I guess they're not expecting them and badly handling it.
DateParser.parse("2024-11-15T11:37:48.256593Z", DefaultFormats.lossless).instant
// ❌ 1731670924593 = GMT: Friday 15 November 2024 11:42:04.593

DateParser.parse("2024-11-15T11:37:48.256Z", DefaultFormats.lossless).instant
// ✅ 1731670668256 =  GMT: Friday 15 November 2024 11:37:48.256

The difference between the two dates in 256 seconds, which is what is supposed to be the milliseconds number.
I.e. they're probably parsing 256593 as a number of milliseconds instead of microseconds.

Note that the standard java.time already provides such parsing methods. I'm not sure why you would use the ones from json4s directly.

See https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/1565
